# Joining multiple Excel workbooks and worksheets using R

Tags: r, join, merge, xlsx, xlconnect

I have a series of Excel workbooks and worksheets that I would like to join in R, but looking at packages like XLConnect or xlsx I only see append and cell merge functions (there are no merge worksheet or even merge workbook functions, for instance). Does anyone have a suggestion as to which package I should use and which function thereafter (both for worksheets and workbooks). Thanks!

Comment: I like `openxlsx`. I used it for a big excel project with multiple workbooks. Check out their `loadWorkbook` function and the rest of the documentation to see if it is suitable to your task.

Comment: I think this should do it for you:
http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/Benchmarks/ImportMultipleExcel_L_JDS_Aug2013.pdf

Comment: Also, here's an Excel AddIn that does the same thing, and so much more:
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two Excel files with the following function :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
merge_Two_Excel_Files <- function(path_Excel_File1,
                                  path_Excel_File2,
                                  path_Excel_File_Output)
{
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
  xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File2)
  nb_Sheets1 <- xlWbk1$Sheets()$Count()
  nb_Sheets2 <- xlWbk2$Sheets()$Count()

  for(l in 1 : nb_Sheets1)
  {
    wbSheet <- xlWbk1$Worksheets(l)$Copy(after = xlWbk2$Worksheets(l))
  }

  xlWbk2$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output)
  xlWbk1$Close()
  xlWbk2$Close()
  xlApp$Quit()

  rm(list = ls())
  gc()
}
```